# How to remove unnecessary code added on FB Wall of the user who clicks on FB Like plugin? Code is like [CDATA[//><​!-- PDRTJS_settings?

Tags: facebook

I am totally confused and have no clue about this. I want to add the FB Like button with Like count to my **WORDPRESS** blog. Even if I add the plugin code manually for a post (or the whole blog) or if I use any WordPress Plugin like "Really simple Facebook and Twitter share buttons" or "Share Buttons Simple Use" still I am facing with the same problem.

Basically the LIKE Button is visible for every Wordpress blog post. However if any user clicks on the LIKE button then on the wall of that user there is some unnecessary code which is also posted.

The code is something like this- (image posting is not allowed else it would have been even more clear)

<​!--//--><​![CDATA[//><​!-- PDRTJS_settings_5477582_post_63={"id":5477582,"unique_id":"wp-post-63","title":"My%20NEW%20TEETH","permalink":"http://MYBLOGURL/2012/01/26/my-new-teeth/","item_id":"_post_63"}; //--><​!]]>

Kindly let me know how to remove the entire unwanted code like CDATA....PDRTJS_SETTINGS etc...

Thanks in advance,

Kiran

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can add the like functionality:

- Like Button:
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
- LikeBox:
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/
- Subscribe Button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/

The Like Box and Subscribe Button will only allow you to "like/subscribe" to Facebook Pages. The Like Button will allow people to like either a Facebook Page OR an external URL (eg. yourblog.com). You may want to consider creating a Facebook Page for that blog, as this will allow your followers to be "portable". If a bunch of people like a URL, and that URL changes, the followers will not move with you.

The Like Button will do what you want. To use all the features, you should create a developer account (free) and create a dummy app for your blog. This will give you an ID to use with the JavaScript SDK.

After you've created an app, just head on over to the first link above, put in your URL and grab the code. You should end up with something like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

That will call the Facebook JavaScript SDK. Put that right after the `<body>` tag.

Then you can put the button wherever you want using code this:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://YOUR_WORDPRESS_BLOG.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ralph.
However I am not a php/jquery programmer. as mentioned in my question i want it for my WORDPRESS Blog without any programming. Can anyone tell me where is the <body> tag for Wordpress blog posts located?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Ah, I see. You should simply be able to create an HTML widget and stack both code snippets on top of each other. That will work. The "body" is simply anywhere in the visible canvas where content lives.